# How to use globally installed node modules packages for multiple projects?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I have been following many react tutorials(just getting started). In all of them, node modules are locally installed within each project. But I don't want to download node modules all the time for each project. I want to install node modules(only react related packages like babel, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react and react-dom) globally, which resides in following location in windows (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules) and then refer them for all of my react projects and also bundle them using webpack. How can I do that? I tried searching, but did not get any solution so far. Kindly let me know if there are any options to achieve that.

Thanks.

Comment: What will happen when you upload your project to another server? 
What will happen if you want to share your code with a friend and you send him your source files?

It is not recommended to install this things globally.

Comment: If you keep modules global, then if you want to update one for one project you'll be updating it for all projects - which may introduce backwards compatibility problems and break those projects. To maintain your own sanity, I would learn to love the fact that modules are kept locally and are only one `npm install` away of coming into existence. Its not like you have to do that each day.

Comment: Nope. I wont be updating the modules. As I said, this is just for learning purpose and not for real project. It takes around 20 to 25 mins for each set of installation and it eats up around 500MB for each installation(including all the internal dependencies). As of now, I have spent 20 mins x 12 sample projects of time and 500MB x 12 sample projects of hard disk space. This is what I want to avoid.  Is there anyway I can refer them in webpack config atleast? I tried few, none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Using global package is not a good idea. It is only recommended for development**

You can use `npm link <global-package>` to use your global modules like local.

Link to refer https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm install -g 'package name'` to install it globally.